# parse XML to POJO using xStream library

Tags: xml, xstream

I use Xstream libray to parse xml ,but have a EXception:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element title of type com.mycontacts.model.explain32.Title32 is not defined as field in type java.lang.Object

explain32.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<explain>

<data>
<title name="123"/>
</data>

<data>
<title name="234"/>
</data>

</explain>
```

java bean:

```
public class ExplainXmlBody32 {
    private List<ExplainXmlData32> data = new ArrayList<ExplainXmlData32>();
}

public class ExplainXmlData32 {
    private Title32 title;
}
public class Title32 {
     String name;
}
```

and I parse xml such as:

```
    private void parseXML_explain32(){
        try{
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myxml/explain32.xml";
            String strXML = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)),  "utf-8");
            tvShow.setText(strXML);

            XStream xStream = new XStream();

            xStream.alias("explain", ExplainXmlBody32.class);
            xStream.alias("data", ExplainXmlData32.class);          
            xStream.alias("title", Title32.class);

//          xStream.aliasField("title", ExplainXmlData32.class, "title");
            xStream.aliasAttribute(Title32.class, "name", "name");

            xStream.addImplicitCollection(ExplainXmlBody32.class, "data");
            //          xStream.addImplicitCollection(ExplainXmlData32.class, "titles");

            //           XOAlias.configExplainXml(xStream);

            ExplainXmlBody32 explain32 = (ExplainXmlBody32) xStream.fromXML(strXML);

            System.out.println("explain32, size:" + explain32.getData().size());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the exception info:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element title of type com.mycontacts.model.explain32.Title32 is not defined as field in type java.lang.Object
---- Debugging information ----
class               : com.mycontacts.model.explain32.ExplainXmlBody32
required-type       : java.lang.Object
path                : /explain/data/title
line number         : 5
```

how to improve my code and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Changed ArrayList to List.  Also added definition to XML types.  Data and explain are needed because it didn't make class name and to make it an Element so the code doesn't create an additional tag.

```css
   [XmlRoot("explain")]
public class ExplainXmlBody32
{
    [XmlElement("data")]
    private List<ExplainXmlData32> data = new List<ExplainXmlData32>();
}

public class ExplainXmlData32
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    private Title32 title;
}
public class Title32
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    String name;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry , there is no  [XmlRoot("explain")]  in xStream,and " private List<ExplainXmlData32> data = new List<ExplainXmlData32>();" is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to solve this problem.

change java bean:

```
public class ExplainXmlBody32 {
    private List<ExplainXmlData32> data = new ArrayList<ExplainXmlData32>();
}
```

to

```
public class ExplainXmlBody32 {
    private List<ExplainXmlData32> datas = new ArrayList<ExplainXmlData32>();
}
```

then

in method parseXML_explain32():
change

```
xStream.addImplicitCollection(ExplainXmlBody32.class, "data");
```

to

```
xStream.addImplicitCollection(ExplainXmlBody32.class, "datas");
```

that's it.